# depth of n-syzygy modules

Tags: commutative-algebra

> Let $R$  be a Noetherian local ring, $M$ a finite non-zero $R$-module, and $\Omega^n M$ the $n$-syzygy module of $M$. Then $$\textrm{depth}_R \, (\Omega^n M) =\ ?$$

I suspect $$\textrm{depth}_R \, (\Omega^n M) = \textrm{depth}_R \, (M) + n,$$  but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: It is really the minimum of $\mathrm{depth}_R(M)+n$ and $\mathrm{depth}(R)$.

Comment: @Mohan Your claim is wrong. For $R=K[[X,Y]/(X^2,XY)$ consider $M=R/(y)$ and its first syzygy.

Comment: @Carlos Try two cases: $\operatorname{pd}_RM<\infty$ (use Auslander-Buchsbaum formula) and $\operatorname{pd}_RM=\infty$ (in this case the best you can get is an inequality).

Comment: @user26857 You are right, I was tacitly assuming $R$ is CM.

Comment: @Mohan I still don't get your claim: if $R=K[[X]]$, and $M=R[[X]]/(X^2)$, then $R$ is CM, depth of $M$ is zero and depth of the $0$th syzygy of $M$ is one.

Comment: What is true is that for every $n\ge 1$, the inequality $\operatorname {depth}_R \Omega^n(M) \ge \min \{n, \operatorname {depth} R\}$     holds                           
                                                                             (for any finitely generated module $M$ over any Noetherian local ring $R$)